# sum column based on unique key sum_distinct

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to sum (not count) a column that belongs to distinct rows

I have the next crossed orders-recipe table:

```
cross_ingredient_product <- data.frame(
  
  day = c(
    "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
    "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
    "Tuesday", 
    "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"
  ),
  order_id = c(
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4
  ),
  product = c(
    "coffee", "coffee", "coffee", "jam_toast", "jam_toast",
    "coffee", "coffee", "coffee",
    "croissant",
    "milkshake", "milkshake", "milkshake" 
  ),
  ingredient = c(
    "coffee beans", "milk", "sugar", "jam", "toast",
    "coffee beans", "milk", "sugar",
    "freezed_croissant",
    "milkshake powder", "milk", "sugar"
  ),
  qty_ingredients = c(
    0.09, 0.7, 0.007, 0.12, 2,
    0.09, 0.7, 0.007,
    1,
    0.14, 0.23, 0.002
  ),
  qty_ordered = c(
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2,
    1,
    3, 3, 3
  )
)
```

And I would like summarise the orders so that I have the ingredients I spent and the products I sold.
My failed try was

```
ingredient_report <- cross_ingredient_product %>% 
  group_by(
    day, ingredient, product
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    qty_ingredients = sum(qty_ingredients),
    qty_products = n_distinct(
      order_id, product
    ),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

It failed because on Monday I sold 3 coffees (not 2), and on Friday I sold 3 milkshakes (not 1).

I intend something like

```
ingredient_report <- cross_ingredient_product %>% 
  group_by(
    day, ingredient, product
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    qty_ingredients = sum(qty_ingredients),
    qty_products = sum(
      distinct(order_id, product, qty_ordered)[["qty_ordered"]],
    ),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want but maybe this:

```
library(dplyr)
cross_ingredient_product %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = ingredient, values_from = qty_ingredients) %>%
  summarize(across(-order_id, ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), .by = c(day, product))


# A tibble: 4 × 10
  day     product   qty_ordered `coffee beans`  milk sugar   jam toast freezed_croissant `milkshake powder`
  <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>             <dbl>              <dbl>
1 Monday  coffee              3           0.18  1.4  0.014  0        0                 0               0   
2 Monday  jam_toast           1           0     0    0      0.12     2                 0               0   
3 Tuesday croissant           1           0     0    0      0        0                 1               0   
4 Friday  milkshake           3           0     0.23 0.002  0        0                 0               0.14
```

Comment: the real question is extend n_distinct to make an operation over a column instead only count rows.